# two foreign keys in mysql(INNO DB)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
id box_name hidden

---------------------------

id item_name box_id hidden
```

so the foreign key is box_id, if the box is deleted or updated it touches also the child items, but how can I make the same with the hidden fields, they are indexes with the same type int(11), if I hide some box, all the children are hidden, but how to hide only the children who references to the box_id -> id, those hidden???

or in other words, how to make 2 foreign keys

Comment: The question would be easier to follow if you had assigned a name to tables but... Do you want to keep the value of the `hidden` columns in synch??

Comment: I don't know how to explain it right, but I just want to hide all the items of the hidden box, not all the items, only those whos parent is hidden

Comment: by now if I delete the box all the items are deleted to, the same is with updates, but how to make the same with the hidden fields?

Comment: But what the heck does "to hide" mean in relational databases context? You cannot "hide" a column!

Comment: no no, i mean if IN the boxTable i set the hidden to 1, then all the hidden fields from the children records itemTable also changes to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by adding unique constraint on parent table `id,hidden` fields and changing your detail table so it has FK to (`id,hidden`) rather than to just `id`. However, in this case I don't see why you need to store `hidden` attribute in detail table since it's always the same as parent `hidden`.

I'd rather add an after update trigger on master table that updates all necessary rows in detail table[s].

**Update**. Example.
1st approach

```
CREATE TABLE boxTable(id int not null auto_increment primary key,hidden 
tinyint not null,
...
CONSTRAINT UQ_BOXTABLE(id,hidden));
CREATE TABLE childTable(...., boxId int not null, hidden tinyint not null,
 CONSTRAINT FK_childTable_BoxTable FOREIGN KEY (boxId, hidden) REFERENCES 
 boxTable(boxId, hidden) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ;
```

every time you change `hidden` in boxTable it will be automatically updated in `childTable`.

2nd approach (double check syntax, I don't have mysql at the moment)

```
CREATE TRIGGER AU_boxTable AFTER UPDATE ON boxTable 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF (new.hidden <> old.hidden) THEN 
    update childTable set hidden = new.hidden WHERE boxId = new.id;
  END IF;
END;
```

2nd approach allows you changing `hidden` fields in childTable regardless of value in `boxTable`, the first doesn't.

Comment: I just want to change those hidden fields, who have the itemTable.box_id = boxTable.id

Comment: the hidden fields are indexes, i can't add unique constraint I get an error of duplicate entry of hidden_2, hidden_3 etc..

Comment: If I hide the some of the boxes, all the items inside that box are hidden to, but by now if i hide one of the boxes, all the items are hidden not matter to what box they belong, why is that?

Comment: @Zecrow : I'm not sure I follow. 1.If `boxTable.id` is unique itself, then `boxTable.id,boxTable.hidden` is also unique.  2. I cannot tell why all the items are hidden without seeing code

Comment: i mean if IN the boxTable i set the hidden to 1, then all the hidden fields from the children records itemT

Comment: @ Zecrow :  I added some examples to the answer; I hope it will be more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've misunderstood the purpose of foreign keys. They're basically designed to enforce referential integrity, so you cannot physically store a foreign key whose target row does not exist. And they also aid in maintaining such integrity, so when you attempt to remove a row that's referenced in another table you're either not allowed to or you get a cascaded deletion.

But there's no way to use foreign keys to perform arbitrary cascaded updates. They're simply not designed for it.

Perhaps you're thinking of **triggers** :-?